# Xonsh error while importing module PyPDF2

Tags: xonsh

I am having trouble importing modules from within xonsh script that are installed in to the virtual environment.

I installed the virtual environment using vox

```
xontrib load vox
vox activate venv
pip install PyPDF2
```

Here is my minimal example

```
#!/usr/bin/env xonsh
import PyPDF2
```

If I run this from within the Python interpreter it works:

```
 $ python         
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyPDF2
>>>
```

If I try to run the xonsh script as a script I get the following:

```
$ ./minimaltest.x
                                                                 sh             
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp, stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xonsh", line 4, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 24019, in main
    _failback_to_other_shells(args, err)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 23983, in _failback_to_other_shells
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 24017, in main
    return main_xonsh(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 24060, in main_xonsh
    run_script_with_cache(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 3043, in run_script_with_cache
    run_compiled_code(ccode, glb, loc, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xonsh/__amalgam__.py", line 2948, in run_compiled_code
    func(code, glb, loc)
  File "./minimaltest.xsh", line 2, in <module>
    import PyPDF2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

Any thoughts about what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xonsh` can only import modules that exist in the same `venv` that it is installed in.  If you install `xonsh` into the same `venv` as `PyPDF2` it should work.

Comment: Ok, will try that out but it does raise the question of "what then is the point of Vox"?

Comment: `venv` and `virtualenv` tend not to play nice with `xonsh` since they make assumptions about `bash` or `zsh` behavior.  the point of `vox` is to allow users to manage python virtual environments.

Comment: I will accept this as correct answer because it worked.